# Battery C rating

Tags: battery-charging

Does the C rating give the peak current of a battery?

Say 10 Ah battery with a C-rating of 0.5C can it discharge 10 Amps current for 60 minutes?

or a 100 Amps current for 6 minutes?
Will it not overheat?

**Or it can discharge a maximum current of 5 Amps for 120 minutes?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C rating of a battery gives the maximum safe continuous current you can draw from it.

A 10 Ah battery with a 0.5C rating will be able to discharge at 5 A in nominally 2 hours. It will be less time than this, as discharging faster than at which the capacity was rated gives you a lower capacity. Lead acid batteries tend to be rated at 20 hours, as this gives the highest headline capacity.

It will probably deliver 10 A, but it will last less than 60 minutes, and it's not rated to sustain that current without the possibility of some mishap, for instance much reduced cycle lifetime or battery overheating.

It will probably deliver 100 A if connected to a suitable load. See the previous paragraph, but more so.

As @jcaron points out in comments, the terminal voltage will drop as the current increases. You would expect the drop in terminal voltage to be 'small', it may even be specified in the data sheet, for currents up to the C rating. Above that current, you may get rather less terminal voltage than you expect. This is what I was trying to hint at in my paragraph above, 100 A into a 'suitable' load. In this case, the load would probably need to be a short circuit as you could expect the drop in terminal voltage to be significant.

Comment: It should also be noted that since batteries have internal resistance, drawing 10 or 100 A will reduce the available voltage, possibly well below what the load requires.